# Unable to publish npm package

Tags: npm, npm-package, npm-publish

Whenever I try to publish my npm package I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code EPIPE
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -32
npm ERR! write EPIPE
```

And sometimes I got another error:

```
npm ERR! network timeout at: .....
```

Is there's a solution to this problem? or another way to publish my npm package?